# firebase queue triggering several times, i dont know why

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm trying the firebase-queue example, but the queue is  triggering several times, and I don't understand why.

```
var Queue = require('firebase-queue');
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://scm-queue-inspeccion.firebaseio.com/');
var randomString = require('random-string');



function toTest() {
    var obj = {
        idInspeccion: randomString(),
        placa: randomString()
    }
    rootRef.child('workers').child('inspecciones').child('queue').child('tasks').push(obj)
}

function start() {
    console.log('started');

    var queueRef = rootRef.child('workers').child('inspecciones').child('queue');


    var queue = new Queue(queueRef, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {
        // Read and process task data
        console.log(data);

        // Do some work
        progress(50);

        // Finish the task asynchronously
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
        }, 5000);
    });

}

start();
toTest()
```

Here's my [github project](https://github.com/correasebastian/queueInspeccion/)

Comment: What is the output you get vs the expected output?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce with the linked repo using node 4.3.1, does it happen every time?